# Replace the :make command with a custom script in vim

Tags: xcode, macos, vim, makefile

I use MacVim as my editor within Xcode.  By default Command-B and :make are bound to call 'make' from the command line.  As we're using Xcode for building and project configuration, I'd like to replace the :make/Command-B calls to make with an applescript command. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try :help makeprg

You use :set makeprg=xxx to change the command that is executed.

Comment: That did the trick.  Here's the final command in my vimrc:

set makeprg=osascript\ -e\ \"tell\ application\ \\\"Xcode\\\"\"\ -e\ \"build\"\ -e\ \"end\ tell\"

Comment: I use vim on my mac, but rarely with Xcode. I will have to give it a try. Thx for the Xcode command.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run an XCode build from CLI, the command is xcodebuild.
I have never tried it inside vim, though.